# php not running on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, apache2, php

OS: ubuntu 14.04

Apache2: 2.4.7

php: 5.5.9

I've just made a fresh install a few days ago. Then install LAMP, set up apache virtual hosts, etc. Everything seem to be running fine... except for php.

phpinfo() works ok, but that's it. Any other *.php just give me a blank page, regarless whether it is right at /var/www/html/ or in a virtual host.

It seems that I need to enable php somewhere, for the past few days I've read every post I could find but nothing seems to work. I appreciate if anyone could point me in what direction to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PHP page that gives you a blank page is often the result of a PHP error, but with display_errors turned off.

You should check the server's error log (usually located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) to see if the errors are being reported there.

Comment: That was the place to look! I thought it had to be something **stupidly obvious**... and it was. I had a tag _<?=php_ in a 30-line script :( Thanks!